# Is it possible define a route-link inside v-icon?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

It is my firt time using vue.js. Is it possible include a `to` router-link inside v-icon? similiar to we use a  tag between

`Header Component`

```
<template>  
    <v-app-bar app>

             <span class="group pa-2">
              <v-icon medium>mdi-home</v-icon>
             </span>


</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<v-btn  icon id="no-background-hover" to="/home">
 <span class="group pa-2">
    <v-icon medium>mdi-home</v-icon>
    </span>
 </v-btn>


<style lang="scss">
#no-background-hover::before {
   background-color: transparent !important; <= can set to any color you want
}
</style>
```

Hope useful

Comment: Thanks A.khalifa, very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a v-btn icon

```
<v-btn icon :to="{ name: 'foo', params: { id:id }}">
     <v-icon>  mdi-pencil </v-icon>
</v-btn>
```